# Would like to rename angular-dart to angulardart

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I am the original author of AngularJS framework. Internally we have had many debates about how should we write our name and we decided that it should be AngularJS, it is written that way in our documentation and if you search the web you will get most hits for AngularJS (vs Angular.js or Angular.Js or angular-js, etc...). On SO we have the tag `angularjs`. (We are happy.)

We now have new project AngularDart, and would like to be consistent with AngularJS and have tag `angulardart`. However two tags already exists `angular-dart` as well as `angular.dart` which prevents me from creating `angulardart` to be consistent with `angularjs`.

What can I do to create `angulardart` tag?

Comment: Would a synonym from `angulardart` to `angular-dart` be sufficient?  The convention on Stack Overflow is to separate words with dashes, notwithstanding the vendor's flavor of spaces (or the lack thereof).

Comment: Would that be confusing wrt angularjs, which doesn't have a hyphen? We want to help people to understand that angularjs and angulardart are peer concepts. AngularDart is still too new to have a lot of questions, but it will eventually have questions with multiple hyphenated sub-topics, just as AngularJS does.

Comment: What multiple hyphenated sub-topics?

Comment: I think Naomi means `angulardart-di`, `angulardart-routing` etc. I think synonym would be sufficient, but I could not create it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much to be consistent with *your* naming conventions more as to be readable. Our tags don't have capital letters, and "angulardart" looks terrible, IMO. With capital letters, it's pronounced as two separate words, even if *you* don't put a space in between them, and "angular-dart" makes more sense to emphasize those two words. How do I know the project isn't actually pronounced "angu lard art" when you remove all indications of where words begin and end?

I'd much rather see them all under [angular-dart](/questions/tagged/angular-dart). In fact, [this Github page](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki/Welcome-to-Angular) which I just happened across viewing one of the questions in this tag explicitly puts spaces in between Angular and either JS or Dart.

Comment: We came up with angulardart as preference after searching Stack Overflow to see how people are using tags for Angular-related things. There are tags for angularjs-service, angularjs-animation, angularjs-controller, etc... similarly, as AngularDart matures and gets more questions, we'll have ones on angulardart-service, angulardart-animation, etc... Dropping the hyphen makes it a little more clear that angularjs and angulardart are peers, hierarchically speaking.

Comment: PS I also just updated the tutorial doc on GitHub to fix the spacing. We're still in beta and in the process of standardizing our naming in a lot of places. Thanks for the reminder to update the tutorial page as well.